# Calling a Controller class public Void method for another Controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller class , which include the following method:-

```
namespace SV.Controllers
{   
    public class VMController : Controller
    {
public void populateViewData(IEnumerable<VM> vms)
        {
//code goes here
```

now if i am on another controller class, how i can call the `VMController.populateViewDate` method ??

Comment: You'd call it like any other public method... is there something specific not working?

Comment: IMHO its a bad design that you need to call another controller method. I would suggest you to refactor your application

Comment: why it is a bad paractice ? as inside a controller i have a method which populate data , and instead of re-creating this method, i am calling it from the other controller..

Comment: It's bad practice due to [Seperation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using helper methods from other controllers is a bad practice/design in my opinion. You should refactor such methods to an helper class which can be accessed from both controllers. Trivial example:

```
public static ViewDataHelpers
{
    public static void PopulateViewData(IEnumerable<VM> vms)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use this in any controller:

```
ViewDataHelpers.PopulateViewData(viewModels);
```

You could also change it to an extension method if you like:

```
public static void PopulateViewData(this IEnumerable<VM> vms)
{
    // ...
}
```

The call in the controller will look like:

```
viewModels.PopulateViewData();
```

It's just syntactic sugar, result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't increase dependencies between controllers. Each one has its job to do. If you need common methods or properties between them, you can make a base controller class :

```
public abstract class BaseVMController : Controller
{
  protected virtual void PopulateViewData(IEnumerable<VM> vms)
  { 
      // ...
  }
}

public class VMController : BaseVMController 
{
  public void NewMethod()
  { 
      IEnumerable<VM> vms;
      PopulateViewData(vms);
      // ...
  }
}

public class VMController2 : BaseVMController 
{
  public void NewMethod2(IEnumerable<VM> vms)
  { 
      PopulateViewData(vms);
      // ...
  }

  protected override void PopulateViewData(IEnumerable<VM> vms)
  { 
      base.PopulateViewData(vms);
      // some additional behavior ...
  }
}
```

Another good possibility is in Henk Mollema's answer, with a helper class.

Edit : some minor adjustments

Comment: Why make it virtual if your not overriding it? Or public if your only calling it in the inherited classes. I'd say a `protected void PopulateViewData(IEnumerable<VM> vms)` would be adequate. Making **everything** public is my personal pet hate :P

Comment: and if your base class is truly a base it should be abstract. Ok, Ok, I'll stop picking now, promise.

Comment: I understand you well, my goal was to talk about using a base class, i didn't detailed too much, like an example of overriden `PopulateViewData` :)

Answer (score 1):

a controler is just a class, like any other.

```
using SV.Controllers;

namespace SV.Controllers2
{
  public class VMController2 : Controller
  {
    public void NewMethod()
    { 
        //instanciate vms here....
        IEnumerable<VM> vms;
        VMController controller = new VmController();
        controller.populateViewData(vms);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Liam's answer, you can also do like this from your action:

```
IEnumerable<VM> _vms;

return RedirectToAction("VM", "populateViewData", new { vms =_vms  });
```

Comment: Populate viewdata returns void, for that to work it would have to return ActionResult.

Comment: Based on the name I think it's an helper method, not an action of the controller.

Comment: My Bad! I missed void somehow. Indeed! a helper method.